# Node.js client application with Spring Cloud Netflix Eureka

Tags: java, node.js, spring, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I'm using Spring Cloud Netflix Eureka to handle microservices (mcs) routings. One of the mcs's is a Node.js mcs.

I tried using a dependency from npm called [eureka-js-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eureka-js-client), but it always reports 404. I checked out the netflix cloud documentation and saw that the logs from node.js and saw that the service is trying to register via URL:

```
POST http://localhost:8761/eureka/v2/apps/{appID}
```

While the eureka server is located at that port, when I try to ping the URL via postman, I always get 404. I tried to `GET /eureka/v2/apps` as well, but also get 404. When I go to `http://localhost:8761` via browser, I still get the standard eureka dashboard and all of the Spring Boot (eureka client) microservices are registered correctly.

Configuration for the eureka server is pretty simple so far:

```
# bootstrap.yml
spring:
  application:
    name: router
eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    fetch-registry: false

# application.yml
server:
  port: 8761
```

Is there a configuration that I need to set up, or did I miss the point completely?

I'm still tingling with eureka, so sorry if the question is too basic.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you have a public github repo I would love to see a link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is `/eureka/apps` 
not `/eureka/v2/apps` , if you are using spring-cloud-eureka.

Although in [pure eureka github wiki](https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Eureka-REST-operations) it says the context path has v2, it is for pure eureka. If you use @EnableEurekaServer, which is in Spring Cloud Context, the context path of Eureka is changed.

By the way, the dashboard is in spring-cloud-eureka. There is no such looking dashboard in pure eureka

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried looking through the logs and see a new endpoint is registered, couldn't find anything. This helped a lot!